# Kafka streams application high memory usage after scaling broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We noticed a high memory usage of our kafka streams applications after scaling our brokers from 3 to 6 brokers. Is there a link between memory usage of client applications and broker count?

Comment: Your apps may try to communicate more frequently with partition replicas. But what difference do you consider "high"? And how are you detecting it?

Comment: We have several services running on top of AWS Fargate. These services are consuming messaged from Kafka (AWS MSK). Some services where restarting due memory exceptions. In the monitoring dashboards we can see an increased memory usage. Most services had an average memory usage of 40% and now 95%.
There where few services that had low usages around 15% but those are also doubled  in memory usage (around 30%).

Comment: I don't think adding extra brokers would cause this. At least, I have not noticed this when we expanded our own (EC2) clusters

Comment: Agreed to what @OneCricketeer said. I would try to get a heap dump to see where memory goes. -- In the end, it could be that your number of network connections doubled, but it seems unlikely that they would double your memory consumption?

Comment: I will look further into this and try to get a memory dump. I also will contact AWS support to see if it is AWS related. For now, thank you for your replies.